# lisp lists concatenation

Tags: list, lisp, concatenation, common-lisp

How can I write a function which has the parameters two lists and which returns the
concatenation of the two lists, without using append.

> I know how to get the head of the second list but I don't know how to put it in the first one and what should I do if the head of the list is also a list.

Comment: can you please provide some more detail

Comment: I thought about a recursive function that takes the head of the second list and puts it at the end of the first one and the it calls the function for the modified list until the second list is empty.

Comment: Is this homework? Are you looking for a re-implementation of `append` (copy of the 1st lists with the original list tucked at the end) or `nconc` (the original list modified to be the concatenation) or something else (e.g., a concatenation of copies of both arguments)?

Comment: Yes it is homework but I don't know what should I look for, I don't think I am allowed to use predefined functions that concatenates the lists directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you allowed to use LOOP or DO?

Something like this will work:

```
(defun my-concat (x y)
  (loop 
    for o in (reverse x)
    do (push o y)
    finally (return y)))
```

You might want to use recursion if looping is not an option.

Comment: The only thing I was not allowed to use was append so I think I can use this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I had to do this without using `APPEND` (for whatever reason), then I would probably do this:

```
(concatenate 'list list1 list2)
```

Though I sense that this is probably a homework question and this is is likely not the answer you are looking for, you can find more information about `CONCATENATE` in the [HyperSpec.](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_concat.htm)

Comment: I am not sure I am allowed to use it. Yes it is homework question and I think that the goal is to write a recursive function that does the task. But I do appreciate your help.

Comment: If your goal is to write a recursive function, then think about the steps involved. What is the concatenation of a bunch of lists? It is the first element of the first list consed onto the first element of the rest of the first list, until there are no more elements in that list. Then, it is the list you have constructed so far consed onto the first element of the next list, repeating the above steps until there are no more lists to concatenate.